# C++ Method called by JNA

Tags: java, jna

How can I convert C++ method :

```
public (void) BinToSlices (BSTR Bin,LPSAFEARRAY FAR *Slices)
```

in JNA Method ?
I know that in VB6 it's `BinToSlices(ByVal Bin as String, ByRef Slices as Integer())`

I know nothing about C++

thanks

Comment: There's nothing C++ about that method signature, but it *does* imply COM.  See com4j or JACOB for more appropriate COM handling via Java.

Comment: I don't understand, I have the source code of BinToSlices.dll, it's a vcproject, and in vb6 program, it's a direct call :

Public Declare Sub BinToSlices Lib "BinToSlices.dll" (ByVal Bin As String, ByRef Slices() As Integer)

Comment: C is not the same as C++; relevant to this case, linking C++ code is more involved than linking C code.  You code is likely C code making use of COM structures (BSTR at the very least).  BSTR is the COM string data type, so you will need something with COM support to translate between Java String and BSTR.  com4j and JACOB do that.